# WPF DataBinding with Code First Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ef-code-first

I am just getting familiar with WPF databinding. I've figured out most of the basics but I'm having trouble figuring out a couple of things.

First, let's say I have an object called Synth that has a collection of Banks. In turn, a Bank has a collection of Patches. I have a synth window to which I set the DataContext to a single Synth object. I have one listbox (lstBanks) that shows all the banks ({Binding Banks}) and another (lstPatches) that shows all the patches ({Binding ElementName=lstBanks, Path=SelectedItem.Patches}). This all works great. I see the applicable patches when I select a bank.

**Question 1: How can I load a selected Patch into a dialog window with two-way binding, yet cancel those changes if DialogResult = false?**

Right now, I have a patch dialog that receives a patch in the constructor which it sets as its DataContext, but I am only using OneWay binding. This happens on the doubleclick of lstPatches.

```
    private void Patch_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Models.Patch patch = (Models.Patch)((ListBoxItem)sender).DataContext;

        PatchEdit p = new PatchEdit(patch);
        p.Owner = this;
        if (p.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
        {
            // Do stuff if applicable
        }
    }
```

Here is my PatchEdit constructor and OK button event:

```
    public PatchEdit(Models.Patch Patch) : this()
    {
        this.DataContext = Patch;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Models.Patch p = (Models.Patch)DataContext;
        p.Name = txtName.Text;
        p.MidiProgramChangeValue = int.Parse(txtPCN.Text);
        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
```

If the user clicks OK on the patch dialog, that's when I set the properties from the form back to the DataContext. I wasn't sure if this was the best way to do it. I don't want to really save the changes until the user clicks OK on the main synth window. So all bank and patch edits should only remain local, and only be "locally" committed if the user clicks OK and not Cancel on the dialog.

**Question 2: Once a patch is updated via the dialog, how can I get that change reflected in lstPatches?**

I understand that directly navigating my models which are essential of type DBSet aren't Observable. I've seen posts regarding using an Observable collection, but doesn't this just complicate something that is supposed to be easy with WPF databinding? If it's the only way, how do I accomplish this easily using my code first models?

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** Bind to a second/temporary object. If the user cancels, throw it away. If they don't, use it to update your original object. Data-binding doesn't really offer an "undo" or "reset" method.

**Question 2:** No, using ObservableCollection's doesn't complicate things. It is the recommended way of doing things. It is actually much harder to work *without* them.

Comment: Thanks, in regards to Question 1, this is exactly what I'm doing now with OneWay binding, so that's good. For question 2, is there an example you can point me to? How can I wrap my DBSets with IObservable without getting too complicated?

Comment: That's not what you want to do. An  `ObservableCollection<EntityObject>` will manage the updating of the Collection (add/remove), but not properties of each individual object. To handle updating of the individual item, you will want to make a ViewModel for that object that implements `INotifyProperyChanged`. If you do that, you could then make an `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>`.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure if this is correct, but I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in my code first classes. Then, I declared all of my collections as IObservable (public virtual ObservableCollection<Patch> Patches { get; set; }) in my code first classes. Of course, I'm calling my OnPropertyChanged on all properties. This is actually working perfectly now on my Banks listbox. However, my patches listbox is still not updating even though Bank.Patches is an Observable collection. Comments or thoughts?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I had overridden ToString() in Patch and never set a DisplayMemberPath. This explains why It never updated. Once I started using an ItemTemplate with concrete bindings, this started working as expected.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this in the code first classes. Check out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx